# I have php url issue for read pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Now I am developing codeigniter site.
I have one issue.
In order to read&open pdf into web browser.

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");         
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache          
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"".$file."\"");
readfile($filePath);
```

above code $file is filename and $filePath is pdf file path.
When it runs on local server, $filePath is value such as "http://localhost/***.pdf" and it runs well.
But when runs on hosting server, this value is "http://***.com/***.pdf"
And doesn't run.
We can not open with pdf format error.
file content didn't include readed.
I know that is cause of URL issue.
But I have no issue!

Comment: Do you mind explaining why do you have 2 `Content-Type` headers defined?

Comment: are you getting `$file` and `$filePath` values on live server ?

Comment: Also make sure you do not have any file permission issue just in case.

Comment: Thank you.but what is live sever?And i add permission already.  $pdfObj->Output($filePath, "F");

Answer (score 1):

Your `Content-Disposition` should be `inline` if you want to display the file in the browser and not as a download but I guess it doesn't really matter if you can get it to work.

If your `allow_url_fopen` config in PHP is set to Off, you will not be able to read URL file from within your PHP script.

Anyway, your code should look something like this.

```
<?php

$file = "lesson2.pdf";
$filePath = "http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf";

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");
readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: result is error also."localhost" url is run well, but "http://www.example.com/test.pdf" then , error is occured.

Comment: @BennySudibyo Check your PHP config for `allow_url_fopen`.